# Why is the Paypal sandbox site is changing to regular Paypal site when I click on "Merchant Services"?

Tags: paypal

It seems that they recently changed the Paypal developer site. They seemed to have deleted my old sandbox accounts in the process so I made two new sandbox accounts...one for a seller and one for a buyer. Now when I log in to the sandbox site as one of my test accounts, then click on "Merchant Services" (to create a button), it redirects to https://www.paypal.com/home. It asks me to login and when I try to login with my sandbox account it fails, because it's the regular paypal site. Then I thought maybe they changed it so that you can make a sandbox button from your regular account but that's not the case either. Does anyone else have this issue? Is anyone else having paypal issues today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they changed the website layout, they also changed login. They did not remove your sandbox account.

You need to login with your paypal account, and you can import your old sandbox accounts from there.

About the buttons. Probably not the answer you are looking for, but:

Sandbox is for SDK & API implementations. Since buttons (I presume donate & buy now) always work, there is no need to have a sandbox for it.

> > Click it, does it work? Awesome!

If you do use the SDK/API/Old-API, you can use sandbox accounts for paying stuff, since that is more complex.

Comment: I was using IPN with my button to update the database so I need a sandbox for the buttons. I have a simple page with 4 products where the user checks off what products he/she wants. Then it sends the info in the "custom" field. I was just using a regular Buy Now button and 3 weeks ago I could do this in the sandbox but now I can't. Is there a better way to do what I am doing?

Comment: It really hasn't been as simple as you say for me. I log into the developer site, go to Applications tab, look at Sandbox accounts, find a new one I don't recognise and see none of my old ones. Anyway, the new one doesn't appear to log me in anywhere on the sandbox. It's a mess as far as I can see.

Paypal continues to make life difficult.

Comment: I fixed it. The 'Import data' action was hidden under the nav bar due to poorly rendering css (didn't show in recent Firefox or Safari). Pretty poor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also have same issues., Not able to create payment buttons using 'Merchant Services' link.

Later I find direct link to create and Manage sandbox links

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-designer

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-management